# Link: Jump To ID - 100px

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation at the very top of my website with a fix position, meaning that it always stays on top even when scrolling.

Now I have an anchor:

```
<a href="#someID">Jump to 'something'</a>
<div id="someID">...</div>
```

Problem is: It jumps to the ID on the page, however, it's now covered by the navigation.

Is there a way to jump to a specific location on the website and jump back a few pixels so it's not covered by the navigation?

With JavaScript it's possible, I guess. Is there a way without it though?

Comment: not really unless you have some padding-top on that div. but that will probably mess your layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by introducing an inner element which is set 100px above the element you're wanting to jump to:

```
<div>
    <span id="someID"></span>
</div>
```

Using the following CSS:

```css
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

div span {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/x434919s/2/).